# After editing a large PDF file (more than 300 mb), unable to save as base64

Tags: node.js, pdf, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using pdf-lib to read the file and do some editing then saving the PDF file. I am using below command to save the PDF content to base64, but it is throwing timeout error in AWS Lambda for PDF size more than 300 MB.

```
const content = await PDFDocument.load(url, {
               ignoreEncryption: true
            });
// do the editing then save
const data = await content.saveAsBase64();
```

If I use below command, it's working fine, but it requires storage space to save then I can save it to S3 bucket, but I have a limitation of 512 MB tmp storage in AWS Lambda.

```
const content = await PDFDocument.load(url, {
               ignoreEncryption: true
            });
// do the editing and then save
const data = await content.save();
```

I need a workaround to stream the PDF content directly to the S3 bucket without saving to tmp storage.

Comment: You say you get a timeout error. Are you using the default timeout (I think it's 30 seconds)? If so, you can increase it up to 15 minutes (900 seconds).

Comment: @kevintechie i have tried to increse the default timeout still it is giving error. I think issue is with pdf-lib library.

Comment: @KJ yes, i can drop the idea of using base64 but i want to stream PDF object generated from pdf-lib to s3 directly, do you have any idea about that.

Comment: You can also try increasing the memory size.

Comment: @kevintechie maximum memory size is 512mb, i need more than that.